# How can I visit every instance of a particular class using the python Abstract Syntax Tree?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, flake8

My overall goal is to write a flake8 plugin which lints every instantiation of a certain class: `Foo` which means that I want to traverse the AST of the code and identify every Node which instantiates a `Foo`

It's easy to write a basic linter, which finds `Calls()` where the thing being `Call()-ed` is a `Foo`:

```
class FooVisitor(BaseVisitor):
    def generic_visit(self, node):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Call):
            if isinstance(node.func, ast.Name):
                if node.func.id == "Foo":
                    print("Foo instantiated!!")
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)
```

but then it's trivial to "evade" the linter by simple re-assignment.

```
import Foo
Bar = Foo       
f = Bar()       <----- "f doesn't get linted because Name.id = Bar not Foo"
```

It's easy enough to "fix" this simple case by keeping a list of `Foo` aliases in my visitor:

```
class FooVisitor(BaseVisitor):
    foo_aliases = ["Foo"]

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Assign):
            if isinstance(node.value, ast.Name):
                if node.value.id in self.foo_aliases:
                    self.foo_aliases.append(node.targets[0].id)

        if isinstance(node, ast.Call):
            if isinstance(node.func, ast.Name):
                if node.func.id in self.foo_aliases:
                    print("Foo instantiated!!")
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)
```

but there many are other ways to "evade" my linter.
here are some examples:

```
import Foo

def get_Foo():
    return Foo

Bar = get_Foo()
f = Bar()
```

```
import Foo

def get_Foo():
    return {"foo": Foo}

Bar = get_Foo()["foo"]
f = Bar()
```

```
import Foo

def get_Foo():
    return [Foo]

[f() for f in get_Foo()]
```

etc...

How can I write an general AST visitor which can visit every instantiation of `Foo` accounting for renames, re-assignments, import-aliases and any other "tricks"?

Comment: this is not possible without solving the halting problem -- also your `NodeVisitor` misses the point of `NodeVisitor` -- you should use `def visit_Call(self, node: ast.Call) -> None` instead of overriding `generic_visit`

Comment: if you can express your linter in terms of typing you could probably do this with a type checker such as mypy

Comment: I think it must be possible? Otherwise the python-parser wouldn't know that (for example: `f` is a `Foo` and wouldn't know what `f()` means?

but maybe the answer is that my `Visitor` would have to re-implement the Python parser to do this?

Comment: my point is you would have to _evaluate_ the code to know in all cases what it refers to.  a silly example `cls = getattr(mod, input())` couldn't possibly know whether that's a `Foo` or a `Bar`

Comment: ah... yes I see what you mean. Thanks. 

The original intention behind this question was to write a linter that would warn if you had instantiated a FastAPI router (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#import-apirouter)  without a particular parameter.  This seems like it might be a common idea for people writing custom linters. Whilst as discussed I can't catch EVERY possible use of `Foo` do you know of a canonical way to make the kind of linter I want, even if it's not 100% foolproof?

Comment: that would be fairly easy with typing -- make the parameter non-optional

Comment: The class in question is part of a third party library but I suppose it would be easy to write a small wrapper which enforces the use of the optional parameter. Easier than solving the halting problem with my linter at any rate... 
Thanks for your responses